# Create a New Index Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

Not sure why this isn't working.

Instructions:

// Create a function called indexFinder that will loop over an array and return a new array of the indexes of the contents e.g. [243, 123, 4, 12] would return [0,1,2,3]. Create a new variable called 'indexes' and set it to contain the indexes of randomNumbers.

Tried Solution:

```
let randomNumbers = [1, 3453, 34, 456, 32, 3, 2, 0];
let indexes = [];

function indexFinder(arr){
  for(var i = 0; arr.length; i++){
    indexes.push(i);
  }

  return indexes;
}

indexFinder(randomNumbers);
console.log(indexes);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no real condition test in your `for` loop because `arr.length`, when above 0, is always truthy.

```js
let randomNumbers = [1, 3453, 34, 456, 32, 3, 2, 0];
let indexes = [];

function indexFinder(arr){
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    indexes.push(i);
  }

  return indexes;
}

indexFinder(randomNumbers);
console.log(indexes);
```

But there's a much more concise way of doing this:

```js
const randomNumbers = [1, 3453, 34, 456, 32, 3, 2, 0];
const indexFinder = arr => arr.map((_, i) => i);
console.log(indexFinder(randomNumbers));
```

Comment: Or `Object.keys(arr)` ...though I guess they'd be strings, so `Object.keys(arr).map(Number)`

Answer (score 2):

Another method is using Array.from

```js
const randomNumbers = [1, 3453, 34, 456, 32, 3, 2, 0];
console.log(Array.from(randomNumbers, x => randomNumbers.indexOf(x)));
```

Or we can  use keys

```js
const randomNumbers = [1, 3453, 34, 456, 32, 3, 2, 0];
console.log([...Array(randomNumbers.length).keys()])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the condition within that `for-loop` using just `arr.length` because for length greater than `0` will be always `true`.

An alternative is using the function **[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**:

```js
let randomNumbers = [1, 3453, 34, 456, 32, 3, 2, 0],
    indexes = Array.from({length: randomNumbers.length}, (_, i) => i);
    
console.log(indexes);
```

Another alternative is getting the length and then execute a simple `for-loop`.